# Generating data on unlevel background

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, test-data

I want to make an unlevel background and then generate some test data on that using Matlab. I was not clear when I asked this question earlier. So for this simple example

```
for i = 1:10  
for j = 1:10  
f(i,j)=X.^2 + Y.^2  
end  
end
```

where X and Y have been already defined, it plots it on a flat surface. I don't want to distort the function itself, but I want the surface that it goes onto to be unlevel, changed by some degree or something. I hope that's a little clearer.

Comment: At the bottom left of your question is a grey word called `edit`. Click on it and you can edit your question.

Comment: Please refrain from posting the same question multiple times. If you need to refine your previous question, click the edit link to modify it. If you can't see an "edit" link under the question, it is probably because you have 2 different accounts (http://stackoverflow.com/users). Try getting an OpenID login and have these accounts merged so you don't have to duplicate questions, which is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

You create a background the same way you create the signal, or foreground: using a function that applies a value to every pixel. Then you add foreground to background and you're done.

The function [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) is likely to be useful for you.

For example, you can write:

```
%# create x and y coordinates for every pixel in the image
[xx,yy] = ndgrid(1:10,1:10);

%# create foreground
foreground = xx.^2 + yy.^2;

%# create an angled background, where y = -10*x;
background = -xx*10;

%# show all
figure
subplot(1,3,1),imshow(foreground,[])
subplot(1,3,2),imshow(background,[])
subplot(1,3,3),imshow(foreground+background,[])
```